# How to move folders into subfolders with name of first character of the folder to move with support for Unicode characters in folder names?

Tags: powershell

I use this [batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65549119/3074564) written by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) to move folders into other folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B 2^>nul') do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "TargetFolder=!FolderName:~0,1!"
    if not "!TargetFolder!" == "!FolderName!" (
        md "!TargetFolder!" 2>nul
        move /-Y "!FolderName!" "!TargetFolder!\"
    )
    endlocal
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com
endlocal
```

It moves folders with two or more characters in current folder into a subfolder with name being the first character of the folder to move with automatic creation of the destination folder if not existing already.

But the batch script doesn't work if a folder name contains one or more Unicode characters.

Is there a workaround with PowerShell?

For example, it doesn't move a folder with first character being `Ш` (Cyrillic capital letter SHA) into a folder with name `Ш`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, PowerShell handles Unicode characters in file paths (and in general) correctly.

The equivalent of your batch-file code in PowerShell is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ??* |
  Move-Item -Destination { 
    # Determine the target dir - the input dir's first letter -
    # ensure that it exists, and output it.
    New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Join-Path $_.Parent.FullName $_.Name[0])
  } -WhatIf
```

Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the *move* operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want. However, even with
`-WhatIf` the *target directories are created* right away.

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-Directory -Path ??*` gets all directories whose name is made up of at least *2* characters.

  - Compatibility note: As [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi), the original author of the batch-file code in the question, points out, the `-Directory`  switch requires PowerShell version 3 or higher, and to make the code work in v2 as well,
    `Get-ChildItem -Path ??* | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` must be used.
- The [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) command uses a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) to determine the destination (target) directory for each input directory:

  - [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) `-Type Directory` either *creates* the target directory or - thanks to `-Force` returns an *existing one*. In both cases, a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance is output, which tells `Move-Item` where to move the input dir. at hand.
  - [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) determines the full target path from the input directory's own (parent) directory, `$_.Parent.FullName`<sup>[1]</sup>, and the first-letter-of-the-input-dir-name target name, `$_.Name[0]`)

    - Note: Constructing the full target path isn't strictly necessary if you're running the command in the *current* directory, so in this case you could simplify to
      `New-Item -Type Directory -Force $_.Name[0]`

---

<sup>[1] You can also use `$_.PSParentPath`, but, due to a bug in `Join-Path` in PowerShell [Core] as of 7.1, that wouldn't work on Unix-like platforms - see [GitHub issue #14538](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14538).</sup>

Comment: The PowerShell script works fine with PowerShell 3.0 or newer version. It works also fine even on a FAT32 drive with PowerShell 2.0 installed by default on Windows 7 with the first line modified to `Get-ChildItem -Path ??* | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |` according to [How do I get only directories using Get-ChildItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085524/3074564) Thank you for rewriting my batch code as PowerShell script code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @Mofi. I've added the v2 workaround to the answer (fortunately, v2 installations are increasingly rare). I've also added a note to indicate that it was you wrote the batch-file code, which the OP should have done in the question. (I've already given your original answer with the batch-file code a +1)

Comment: I appreciate it, @JackRock.